Is there a way to automatically populate the Quick Open Input field (Ctrl + P) with highlighted text?
So I know that for Find in files (Ctrl + Shift + F), the search input will automatically be populated with what is currently highlighted. Is the same functionality possible for the Quick Open Search Bar (Ctrl + P), or the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P)?
If so where would I configure that? Or are there different approaches to that?
To give a bit more context, I have started to use the Quick Find functionality by pressing Ctrl + P and adding the % symbol, to get a more Webstorm like search experience, and I would love to be able to search for highlighted text without copy/pasting into there.
I tried to find something in the settings, but it seems to me I either don't know what keywords to search for, or it's just not the intentional way to use the Quick Search Bar like that.
